# MVC4 Catch all requests to a controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My app needs to have the ability to let users navigate to a page using the foo.com/pubid convention where pubid is a randomly generated string such as "wgwrfwrcwrf".

My `Home` controller has an Index ActionResult defined:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
         //do stuff
    }
```

When I navigate to this action on my site without specifying an ID everything is fine. I return the view associated to home. This is what bit.ly does. I am trying to translate that ID inside my app.

However if I request a URL such as foo.com/wgwrfwrcwrf I get a 404. I need to be able to catch this string to send it to the right view. Does this require a custom route?

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "id", // Route name
    "{id}", // id route
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

Comment: @Alex, where in the route class did you place this?  The MapRoute order matters.

Comment: @Michael_B I've tried it before and after the default route included in an MVC4 project. No luck with either.

Comment: @Alex It should work if it's before the Default or the only route in the routing class.  Double check that you route is being added.  And check to see if the route is being called when you have no `id` string appended to the url.

Comment: @Michael_B If it is my only route then it "works" but it "breaks" all my other controllers as everything goes to the Index action of home. This doesn't feel like best practice as I think I would have to create a route for every controller and action in my application. Thoughts?

Comment: @Alex maybe place your randomizing info in a route like /r/{id} so you can make sure you aren't catching other routes and breaking code that way.

Comment: @Michael_B that's what I ended up doing although I'm not 100% pleased with that solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a catch-all route like this...

```
    routes.MapRoute("catchall", "{*id}", 
                               new {
                                      controller = "Home", 
                                      action = "Index", 
                                      id = UrlParameter.Optional
                                   });
```

Enjoy :)